# Global variables in Python

Tags: python

Hi I tried the following example (i **don't** have `im` in the global) and found that the program actually runs and outputs 10.

Is Python dynamic scoped?

```
def useGlobal():
    def inSide():
        print 'inside',
        print b
    b = 5
    print im
    inSide()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    im = 10
    useGlobal()
```

Comment: Why do you need global variables? I can not remember having used global variables in my 18 Python years.

Comment: @RestRisiko, that sounds impossible. Note that @Yin's code above uses 3 global variables: `__name__`, `im`, and `useGlobal`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The if statement doesn't create another scope in Python, therefore, the "im" is in the module level, namely, the global scope.